# jQuery script works great with a click, doesn't work with keydown event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm a designer learning jQuery. So please forgive me my lack of understanding ;) I'm trying to put together a carousel kind of thing with one main slide visible and two other partially hidden slides that trigger the next/prev slide action.

I've approarched the topic like this: the partially visible prev/next li's rearrange the ul when a prev/next click is received, making the last li of the ul the first one and vice versa, animated with CSS. I've been able to respond correctly to `li.next` / `li.prev` clicks, but when I try to respond the same way to keypress left/right - it doesn't work.

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="prev" data-id="1">

    </li><!--
    --><li class="main" data-id="2">

    </li><!--
    --><li class="next" data-id="3">

    </li><!--
    --><li data-id="4">

    </li><!--
    --><li data-id="5">

    </li>
</ul>
```

Then the CSS (I know it's lacking the wrapping overflow: hidden div, removed it for clarity):

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

ul li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 95%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    white-space: normal;
    background: #eee;
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul li.main {
    height: 80%;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 15%;
    z-index: 4;
}

ul li.prev {
    height: 75%;
    margin: 0 -8% 0.5% -92%;
    z-index: 1;
}

ul li.next {
    height: 75%;
    margin: 0 0 0.5% -8%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

And now the half-working script:

```
    //this works great

    $('body').on('click', 'li.prev', function() {
        $("body").find( "li" ).eq( 2 ).removeClass("next");
            $(this).next().removeClass().addClass("next");
            $(this).removeClass("prev").addClass("main");
            $(this).prev().removeClass().addClass("prev");

            var $this = $(this), callback = function() {         
$this.siblings(':last()').insertBefore($this).addClass("prev");
                    };
                $this.fadeIn(100, callback).fadeIn(100);
            }); 

            $('body').on('click', 'li.next', function() {
                $("body").find( "li" ).eq( 0 ).removeClass();
                $(this).prev().removeClass().addClass("prev");
                $(this).removeClass().addClass("main");
                $(this).next().removeClass().addClass("next");

                var $this = $(this), callback = function() {            
$this.siblings(':first()').insertAfter($this.siblings(':last()'));
                    };
                    $this.fadeIn(100, callback).fadeIn(100);
                }); 



    // now the left-right keys control attempt

    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        switch(e.which) {

            case 37: // key right
                $("body").find( "ul li" ).eq( 2 ).removeClass("next");
                $("li.prev").next().removeClass().addClass("next");
                $("li.prev").removeClass("prev").addClass("main");
                $("li.prev").prev().removeClass().addClass("prev");

                var $this = $("li.prev"), callback = function() {      
                  $this.siblings(':first()').insertAfter($this.siblings(':last()'));
                    };
                    $this.fadeIn(100, callback).fadeIn(100);
                break;


            case 39: // key left
                $(".body").find( ".view ul li" ).eq( 0 ).removeClass();
                $("li.next").prev().removeClass().addClass("prev");
                $("li.next").removeClass().addClass("main");
                $("li.next").next().removeClass().addClass("next");

                var $this = $("li.next"), callback = function() {      $this.siblings(':first()').insertAfter($this.siblings(':last()'));
                    };
                    $this.fadeIn(100, callback).fadeIn(100);
            break;

            default: return;
        }
    });
```

And here it is put together on fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/nfp828yc/

Could you please help me out and tell me what an I missing to make the left/right keys do the same as the `li.prev`/`li.next` clicks do?

A hughe thanks!

Comment: Firstly, what does `e.which` contain? Does it contain anything for any keys? also, does it contain the right values for the keys you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that in keydown function you have an undeclared `$this` because you are not in the scope. The simplest way is triggering the click when keydown. Look at this:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    switch(e.which) {

        case 37: // key right
                $('li.next').trigger('click');
            break;


        case 39: // key left
                $('li.prev').trigger('click');
        break;

        default: return;
    }
});
```

So you are making the function NEXT / PREV only one time, and then when you press left and right key arrows, the click will be triggered in the correct `<li>`

See it working:

https://jsfiddle.net/nfp828yc/4/

Comment: What? I don't understand your comment @AnoopJoshi :(

Comment: Actually I was about to post the same answer. But then I noticed that, you already posted the answer 40 seconds before..

Comment: Guys, thank you so much @Marcos, and Anoop. This is brilliant, had no idea you could do it this way (I'm starting this jQuery adventure ;), now I know it and I'm a better man :))

Thank you!

Comment: Ah Ok! LOL sorry because I'm faster xD. Note that I was having time to reject an irrelevant edit, to read all code, to identify the problem, to make the fiddle and to write the answer, so this is the faster of the old west ;) good luck next time

Comment: @MarekEkes it's fine, but don't abuse of automatic event triggering, otherwise you obtain unexpected problems and hard to solve issues. In this case there are not problems, but don't abuse ;)

Comment: @Marcos thanks for the tip man! I'll never abuse it ;) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Just trigger the click when hitting the key:

```
case 37: // key right
     $('li.prev').trigger('click');
  break;

case 39: // key left
     $('li.next').trigger('click');
  break;
```